# Getting a null error with scrollIntoView

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im getting the following error with `scrollIntoView`:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null`

Here is my code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(function() {
   var node = document.getElementById('cart');
   node.scrollIntoView();
 }, 0);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: seems that `document.getElementById('cart')` returns `null`, it means that `card` was not found in `DOM` tree